# How to run console with a c++ application

Tags: c++, logging, console, lcc-win32

I need to run a console when the app starts (for debug, log, etc) without a .bat file.
I use the LCC compiler on Windows 7 x86.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the console APIs in Windows, start with AllocConsole.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this is working on Windows, but is there analog of this command on Linux?